# Show that $x_0^2 = 2$ is impossible by showing $x_0^2 = 2$, then $x_0$ is not rational

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

The set S of rational numbers x with $x^2 \lt 2$ has rational upper bounds but no least rational upper bound. Suppose that S has a least rational upper bound and call it $x_0$.

Show that $x_0^2 = 2$ is impossible by showing $x_0^2 = 2$, then $x_0$ is not rational.

---

Is this as simple as showing that $x_0 = \sqrt 2$ and obviously not rational? Or is that not robust enough?

Comment: Do you know the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational? To write this proof you don't really need to know that the number $\sqrt{2}$ exists. You start by assuming that there is $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x^2=2$ and this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: While it's true that $\sqrt{2}$ would be the least upper bound of $S$ if we included all real numbers, that fact isn't relevant to this analysis. The point of this exercise is to suppose that there is a least upper bound in $S$ (which doesn't include $\sqrt{2}$ since it isn't rational) and to show that this assumption leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Showing that a number whose square is $2$ can't be rational is easy. The hard part here is showing that the least upper bound of that set is a number whose square is $2$.

Comment: The question in the title here doesn't align with the body of the question. I've just posted an answer to the question implicit in the body of the question. It would be helpful if the OP could make the title and the body of the question agree. (For future reference, the title in an MSE post is just a title: you should always make it clear in the body of the post exactly what the question is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is basically sound, but not quite watertight. When you say "showing that $x_0=\sqrt 2\;$", you are assuming the existence of the number $\sqrt 2$, which is not available when you are working with the rational numbers. You should instead say "showing that $x_0^2=2\;$".

Then, as you say, once you have shown that $x_0^2$ has to equal $2$, you can use the traditional ancient Greek argument to show that this leads to a contradiction.

And to show that $x_0^2=2$, suppose that $x_0^2>2$ and then exhibit a rational number $q$ such that $2<q^2<x_0^2$. (This requires a bit of thought.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have been set a very dreary logic-chopping problem that is actually incorrect. If you suppose that the set $S = \{x :\Bbb{Q} \mid x^2 < 2\}$ has a least upper bound $x_0$ that is rational, then you have made a false supposition and from it you can conclude any proposition you like, including the proposition that $x_0^2 = 2$.

Comment: I think the blame lies with the OP here, not the person who set the problem. B. Hoffman has taken the uncontroversial statement $x_0^2=2$ and changed it to $x_0=\sqrt 2$, which is (in my opinion) where the problem lies.

Comment: @TonyK: I agree that the post isn't very clear and have just added a comment to that effect. If the problem as set includes the supposition that the set $S$ has a rational least upper bound, then the problem statement is wrong.

Comment: But the point is that such a supposition leads to a contradiction, thereby proving that the original supposition must be false. This is just a standard proof by contradiction, isn't it?

Comment: @TonyK: if you look at the problem implicit in the body of the post, you will see that it says something of the form "suppose falsehood and then show that something else is not false". That's not the pattern of a proof by contradiction, it's just a tautology. We really need to see the problem as actually posed to the OP to see who's right.